# How to convert POST PascalCase json to snake_case in Django Rest Framework?

Tags: python, python-3.x, django, django-rest-framework

I have a DRF API endpoint that accepts python snake_case payloads:

```
{
    "sample_id": "",
    "notes": "",
    "patient_id": "",
    "dob": "",
    "scan_model": {
        "current_time_left": "",
        "scan_state": null,
        "timer_configuration": {
            "timer_interval": null,
            "timer_length": "",
            "warning_span": "",
            "window_of_opportunity": ""
        }
}
```

How to get the endpoint to accept a json with keys in PascalCase like this:

```
{
 "SampleId": null,
  "Notes": null,
  "PateintId": "testid",
  "DateOfBirth": "05/11/1995",
  "ScanModel": {
    "Id": 1,
    "CurrentTimeLeft": "00:00:00",
    "ScanState": 6,
    "TimerConfiguration": {
      "TimerInterval": 200,
      "TimerLength": "00:15:00",
      "WarningSpan": "00:02:00",
      "WindowOfOpportunity": "00:05:00"
    }
}
```

I am using Django 4.1, DRF 3.14 and python 3.11
Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So you can achieve this by using the `JSONParser` class and a custom `JSONRenderer` class.

You can create a custom JSONRenderer class that overrides the default render method to convert PascalCase keys to snake_case before rendering the data.

So this will be your renderer:

```
import json

class SnakeCaseJSONRenderer(JSONRenderer):
    def render(self, data, media_type=None, renderer_context=None):
        # convert data keys to snake_case
        data = json.loads(json.dumps(data, separators=(',', ':')))
        return super().render(data, media_type=media_type, renderer_context=renderer_context)
```

Then in your views you can use this custom renderer by setting the `renderer_class` attribute as your custom renderer class.
Like this:

```
from rest_framework import viewsets

class MyViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    renderer_classes = [SnakeCaseJSONRenderer]
```

Or you can add it to the settings too:

```
REST_FRAMEWORK = {
    'DEFAULT_RENDERER_CLASSES': [
        'rest_framework.renderers.JSONRenderer',
        'rest_framework.renderers.BrowsableAPIRenderer',
    ]
}
```

You can also use this [package](https://pypi.org/project/djangorestframework-camel-case2/)